# Create jQuery selectmenu from templated html

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

If I create HTML with a jQuery-template and then immediately try to reference an item in that HTML to create a jQuery-UI element out of it it doesn't work:

```
$(".drop-down-container").loadTemplate(...)
$("#directories").selectmenu();
```

If I add a setTimeout and only call selectmenu after a delay, it works. Is there some handler I can use so I don't have to count on a delay?

I read elsewhere to use class instead of id, but in my case that makes no difference. Unless I use a delay, class also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the [jquery-template](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template) . You can pass have different options to the load template.

> There are a number of options the plugin accepts. These can be set by
>   passing an object containing the settings you would like to set as the
>   third parameter to .loadTemplate:

```
$(container).loadTemplate(template, data, { append: true, elemPerPage: 20 });
```

> "complete" (default null) - Callback function to call on complete.
>   Will always be called regardless of success or failure.
>
> "success" (default null) - Callback function to call on successful
>   completion.
>
> "error" (default, outputting error message to template container) -
>   Callback function to call on error.

There are other options available with jquery-template.

Comment: Oops RTFM. Yes 'success' callback works for me, thanks.